# Is there a way to deal with slow-loading document.write scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

The embed code from a third-party chat site has recommended embed code as follows:

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='https://site.com/script.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

and the external Javascript itself also contains `document.write` code. This means that a traditional deferred load strategy stops the script from working completely. Not having deferred loading is an issue because the script can sometimes take up to 90 seconds to load, which blocks the entire page's DOMReady event.

Is there anything I can do on my own site (given I have no control over the embedded script) to deal with performance issues? Don't mind if the solutions won't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in an iframe - even it blocks, it blocks a different document. You can also put it in the bottom of the page (so it won't delay the page) and then move the resulting HTML around in the DOM to where you want it - this is a more dangerous tactic because it might screw up the chat code.

Comment: It's already at the bottom of the page - because the scripts execute immediately in document.write the DOMReady event is blocked. So that won't help.

Comment: iFrame is an interesting idea though, will see if I can cook something up.

Comment: ahhh... right, moving scripts to the bottom *will* help to not delay the content of the page, but it can't help with DOMLoad

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to put the script tag as close to the end of the document as possible (before the  tag). And you can add your script via such function:

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");

        script.type = "text/javascript";

        //callback functionality
        if (!!callback && Ext.isFunction(callback)) {
            if (script.readyState) { //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "compleate") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        callback();
                    }
                };
            } else { //other browsers
                script.onload = function() {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

instead of using

```
document.write('...')
```

Comment: I already said that wouldn't work due to the script itself using document.write.